# Offline Map for Iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

My new iphone application need an offline map (google map or any).User can use the Map without net connection.

Any Map SDK available for iphone for offline purpose?

anybody know?help is highly appreciable

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: take a look at open street map :)

Comment: i think it's not possible without internet

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go here is to use the OpenStreetMap project. With it you can generate high quality maps, fully customizable and scriptable for you application. You can also take them offline by creating your own map tiles. There are different approaches for that. (See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap).

As a map renderer I recommend the LeafletJS JavaScript library.

I am not aware of any iOS SDK for this but you could show the map in an UIWEbView.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare the map with MapTiler and then display on the iOS device

http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/ios/